# Why does address sanitizer overlook seg faults sometimes?

Tags: c, gcc, address-sanitizer

Been using `fsanitize=address` while compiling C programs, in order to track seg faults for about a year now. Every now and then I encounter a strange behavior, my program would be seg faulting if compiled **without** `fsanitize=address` but when I compile **with** `fsanitize=address` this seg fault disappears. I have looked around the web but haven't been able to figure out exactly why this might be happening.
I know that `address sanitizer` is not a perfect program but just don't know exactly why it has this behavior.

Comment: When you have an undefined behavior in your program, any change in it or in compiler options can change the observed behavior.

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

A part of AddressSanitizer algorithm intersperses all local and global variables (and heap allocations) with 32-byte gaps to detect overflow. Thus off-by-one overflows which used to corrupt other variables (and likely cause crashes if those variables were pointers or offsets) may no longer do this and corresponding faults will disappear.

Asan should still report errors for such overflows which apparently it does not in your case. This may be uncovering some issue in Asan or (more likely) the way you run it (e.g. not combining it with `-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE` or `-fno-common` as explained in [FAQ](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer#faq))